# python-pptx on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, buildout

According to Google App Engine Third Party Libraries Support, the latest version of **lxml** supported is **2.3**
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

And python-pptx requires lxml **>= 3.1.0**
https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/master/requirements.txt

So what's the best way (if possible) to run **python-pptx** on **GAE**?

Note: I'm using **buildout** to deploy my applications, and that where those restrictions fail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Engine isn't compatible with that library so your best bet if you still want to stick with App Engine services is to use Managed VMs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/

This will let you access all the App Engine services but give you more flexibility with installing libraries.

Comment: Thanks @PizzaPanther... this helped me to discard this library and just focus on something else.. just can't make it work on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I wanted to use Python-pptx with GAE standard environment but wasn't able because GAE standard doesn't support Pillow. I migrated to GAE flexible environment and it works perfectly. Took a few hours to adjust my code for the flexible environment but its no big deal.